# tooltip in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello guys I am using the `ErrorProvider` in C# but I am not satisfied of it. I want it to be like this. The tooltip appears only in the mouse pointer. Any ideas about this?

**I Want it to be like this**:

[image: popup tooltip]

Comment: Can you please describe more about what you want to achieve and about your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ErrorProvider like this:

`errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "UserName is required")`

If you want to set the error in response of user action, when react on `Validating` event from the textbox. Once the user typed in the new data `Validated` event will be fired, and at that moment you can erase the error:

`errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, null)`